# javascript- find price in html document with largest font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the price in an html page, and I need it to work for various html structures. My assumptions are that 1) prices are wrapped in their own html tag, and 2) the price I want is the one that has the largest font size. Using javascript and jQuery, how could I build an array of html elements that contain a $, and order them by font size?

Comment: Are we allowed to use jQuery here?  Or just native javascript DOM methods?

Comment: @Mercury he has added jquery tag too

Comment: Yes, jquery is allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved using jQuery and with a sort function quite simply assuming the following HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <span style="font-size: 15px;">$10</span>
    <span style="font-size: 25px;">$10</span>
    <span style="font-size: 10px;">$10</span>
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">$10</span>
</div>
```

```
var $prices = $.makeArray($('div *:contains($)'));
$prices.sort(function(a,b){
    var fontSizeA = parseFloat($(a).css('font-size')),
        fontSizeB = parseFloat($(b).css('font-size'));
    return fontSizeA - fontSizeB;
});
```

You would get an array of `<span>` DOM elements like this:

```
[
    <span style="font-size: 10px;">$10</span>,
    <span style="font-size: 15px;">$10</span>,
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">$10</span>,
    <span style="font-size: 25px;">$10</span>
]
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/e7EE2/) - Here you can try adding additional elements and changing the font size with CSS. Edit the jQuery selector as you need to.